# Duplicate files in .NET 5 MVC project

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am baffled at a series of errors I'm coming across.

I have a .NET 5 MVC project that we've been working on for school for a few months now. Suddenly, I was getting duplicate content warnings. After some digging, I found that setting `EnableDefaultContentItems` to `false` seemed to do the trick. Things were great for a couple weeks, until suddenly appsettings, views, css/js files etc. stopped deploying to the output directory. After some more digging, I found that you have to also set the content items, so I did that. So my csproj file looks like this now:

```
  ... 
  <PropertyGroup>
    <EnableDefaultContentItems>false</EnableDefaultContentItems>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="wwwroot/**" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
    <Content Include="appsettings*.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
    <Content Include="Views/**/*.cshtml" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
    <Content Include="Areas/**/Views/**/*.cshtml" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
  </ItemGroup>
  ...
```

But now comes the part where I'm pretty sure my computer is haunted. Today, Razor runtime compilation has stopped working, and when I went into my bin folder, there were hundreds of files duplicated anywhere from 5 to 60 times.

[image: finder window]

Is there any way to fix this? I have no clue why this started happening randomly (I haven't updated the project references, nor the core framework). I'm developing on a Mac if that makes any difference.

Comment: Try to remove the <ItemGroup> element containing  <Content...../>.These items are already included by the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web and are therefore defined twice.

Comment: That’s one of my issues. If I remove that, none of my content items are included. I had to set the default behavior to false, which means I have to include that section.